# Why does nginx write max 16413 bytes to socket?

Tags: sockets, nginx

Nginx writes to FDs maximum 16413 bytes, also there is a lot of `-1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)` after write

Why is that?

I thought that trouble is in net.ipv4.tcp_wmem configuration and change it to `net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 4194304`, it doesn't help

Strace log:

```bash
epoll_wait(29, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=526027040, u64=139844661184800}}], 512, 8) = 1
write(37, "3Q\233\201:z(\301\355\306\330\25f\342I`\321\236~\370\243\371\356-0h\250\330t\231Pm"..., 1328) = 1328
write(37, "\27\3\3@\30\302\v\240\3032\273\251\273\267F'+i\271\226\361-\264\347\202\337\375WeBE\250"..., 16413) = 16413
write(37, "\27\3\3@\30\302\v\240\3032\273\251\274\7\23\274\200\253H?%\3276\305\224\204\20T\f\202\25\253"..., 16413) = 16413
write(37, "\27\3\3@\30\302\v\240\3032\273\251\275v\260\241\223\250\303\353N*\202\310#\204\251\245\1\245}\324"..., 16413) = 16413
write(37, "\27\3\3@\30\302\v\240\3032\273\251\276\241\312\310\276\344\265]<\330\"\2016$\37\215\36\345x\3"..., 16413) = 16413
write(37, "\27\3\3@\30\302\v\240\3032\273\251\277\302<e\21\241\213A-\345\265\246\271v,w5c\225\200"..., 16413) = 16413
write(37, "\27\3\3@\30\302\v\240\3032\273\251\300\353O\204\36,\377\260\7\21\341\3L\307\345t\6\6\274\377"..., 16413) = 2739
write(37, "\206\241\34\342F\345\272\216\336\2@\27cE\204 )\211\261\3744\365\305Z\367O\276\nA\35(K"..., 13674) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(65, "\25\3\3\0\32\234\206\273\n(\224\346G\7\317\363<#\357~\242d\213\16\345\231\371\340vY\253", 31) = 31
close(65)                               = 0
epoll_wait(29, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=526029921, u64=139844661187681}}], 512, 352) = 1
write(119, "s\243\6h\243\303-\317\344\0F\332\237<C\17\370\252\257\242\263\364\34\232=\302Y\177\4\177\241C"..., 5186) = 5186
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\270\242Q\374\223\3\334\375@\357\276m\252\253o\372\rv7\6"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\271\365G\320\350[ \313\231\223\302\262O\302\202\246^:R_"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\272\311\274B'\372\262\24\277Ti5\245\7(q3ms\7"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\273s\363c5\16D\204(+\210,\2335zKN)\10\362"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\274\350\220&\330,Z\220_.\241\345\212\224\7\344\266\30\341\334"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\275\351\3642\374\355\30c\317C\356Aa\324\vj.\\\203\340"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\276.\313i\326*\303\271B\254\30159:\215\235#\265\16\274"..., 16413) = 16413
write(119, "\27\3\3@\30\214\rA9=\216x\277[\275\266\316$P\275\227\334\312\\\236\362\362R\242\261Q\227"..., 16413) = 8403
write(119, "i(\242\200\233\204\322\366J\342\3772\325U\261\23\26\215_\362\356q\221\214=?\314\235\345\263\30\374"..., 8010) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(29, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=526006400, u64=139844661164160}}], 512, 348) = 1
write(39, "\244\v\27\363\341\271\6\273\rt\"\236\200\305Z\v\261@8'\271\336#\373\n\247v\16~aY\267"..., 3180) = 3180
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\240\337\242\332\355\372\210.\260\f\22](\\\33PK'I\341"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\241\224\r5 \340`\223\305T\n\211*\203q\352\200\341\270l"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\242\234\273\242\23\373\2162\244\257M\0064\341\0160\37\262\242*"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\243\32\357 8\253M\306#?ub`\201\241t\25\277+\n"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\244\244h\267\313\32t\251\fw2\342\336I\375P\2121\263\201"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\245_\271\342\23\350\362V'\324\362\351g\322\360\255R=\34\321"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\246b\367\22\3004^.\351\3616\351&\352\266\333\5:\317I"..., 16413) = 16413
write(39, "\27\3\3@\30D\34\216\23\372\177\254\247\365#\365z\2154MQ\271\275w\3002c\204\335\24a3"..., 16413) = 9705
write(39, "\321\204\316\226k\210\340,_'q>\\\365K\210\2202:f\301\223,\267D\324\263A\326\16\2b"..., 6708) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Comment: What is the socket's `SO_SNDBUF` buffer size set to? Assuming you are using a TCP socket, `EAGAIN` would mean that you are trying to write to a non-blocking socket that is not writable, ie its send buffer is full or the peer's receive buffer is full, so try again later

Comment: I just tried to set it in listen dirictive (listen 443 ssl reuseport sndbuf=32768;), but he still writing 16413 bytes into FD :(

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your actual code. But just based on your logging, I'm guessing that you are sending faster than the peer is receiving, causing the peer's receive buffer to fill up. For example: `write(..., 16413) = 2739` tells you that it attempted to send 16413 bytes but only 2739 bytes were sent. The peer's receive buffer likely filled up. `16413 - 2739 = 13674` bytes left over, so `write(..., 13674) = -1` attempted to send the remaining bytes but failed, thus `EAGAIN` if the receiver didn't have buffer space available. The same behavior occurs in the other `EAGAIN` errors.

Comment: Thx for the EAGAIN explanation. Left one more question :D Whu nginx always send 16413 bytes

Comment: I can't answer that, but nginx is open-source so feel free to look at its source code for yourself.